# appending the input attribute value differs from text value

Tags: jquery

On looping i am getting  value from json, and place in to input checkbox both values and text, but i am getting wrong outupt, it is difference from text value from attribute values

my loop:

```
$.map(data["allLocales"], function(value, i){
    if(i % 5 === 0 ){
        col0 += "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
    } else if(i % 5 === 1) {
        col1 += "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
    } else if(i % 5 === 2) {
        col2 += "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
    } else if(i % 5 === 3) {
        col3 += "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
    } else if(i % 5 === 4) {
        col4 += "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
    }
})
```

example of wrong htmls:

```
<label class="blue"><input value="Italian" type="checkbox">Italian</label>
<label class="blue"><input value="Italian" (italy)="" type="checkbox">Italian (Italy)</label>
<label class="blue"><input value="Italian" (switzerland)="" type="checkbox">Italian (Switzerland)</label>
```

what is wrong here..? I am looking exactly both the attribute and text value should be same

Comment: can you show us your json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to not be quoting your results properly, which is especially important when dealing with spaces. For example,

```
    "<label><input value="+ value.name +" type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
```

when fed with `Italian (italy)` is being rendered as:

```
    <label><input value=Italian (italy) type='checkbox' />Italian (italy)</label>
```

`(italy)` is then being treated as a blank attribute, as per the HTML5 specification, and given a value of `""`.

To fix this, add quote marks around where you output the value:

```
    "<label><input value='"+ value.name +"' type='checkbox' />"+value.name+"</label>"
```

should now render:

```
    <label><input value='Italian (italy)' type='checkbox' />Italian (italy)</label>
```

You may also want to consider escaping any `'` characters that may occur in the value being output, however there's no evidence that they are part of your current dataset.

Comment: I don't get the point of adding a single quote with `.Replace("'", "''")`

Comment: still i am getting a issue as :Uncaught TypeError: Object Afrikaans has no method 'Replace'

Comment: @Brewal In this case, there is none; it would be in situations where a ' is part of the value.

Comment: @3gwebtrain I'll remove that part, as it's obviously caused confusion.

Comment: Yes but I was not talking of that case. If you replace `'` with `''` you will get `value='attribute with ' a single quote'` be `value='attribute with '' a single quote'` which is not valid html.

Comment: @Brewal You're right, was escaping it incorrectly. Should probably have been `&quot;` or `\'`. Have removed that section now, as irrelevant in context anyway.

Comment: @Brewal Thank you, for that recommendation and also for spotting my error. :)